# What are some of the basic results I should report in a statistics project?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

I have been sitting in on a lot of data science/statistics project and I've noticed some inconsistencies when data scientists report their metrics. Is there some resources available that outline the statistical test performed and the appropriate metrics and format to report for the said test?

Here are two examples for my recent experience:

1. One-way repeated measures ANOVA,  Score [F(8,92) = 43.12, p < 0.004, partial n^2 = 0.41]
2. ANOVA, F=1.95, p = 0.015

My question is not limited to just ANOVA, but any statistical test and their corresponding results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's a standard reporting scheme, just the expectations of your readership. Thus, instead of seeking a common reporting standard, I would advise you to understand the needs of your readership and tailor your reports and presentations to them.

A report to the parent-teacher's association about the levels of particulate matter in the classroom would be necessarily less technical than a report to an insurance firm, even if you conducted the same analysis. This is not to say, of course, that one group is smarter or more worthy of the full results than the other. It has to do with the way the information is presented and, sometimes, the stats get in the way.

I teach my students the 1:2:20 rule of thumb. The one paragraph summary goes to the mayor. The two paragraph summary goes to the media. The 20 paragraph report goes on the shelf. I'm not sure that the mayor or the media care about eta-squared results, so I don't provide it to them, but it's there for them to access in the full report and available should they ask for it.

To drive this home, in one of the journals I help edit in which the readership consists mainly of a general medical audience, we would rarely report anything more than a point estimate, the 95% confidence interval and the p-value. For example, "the adjusted odds ratio from the logistic regression was 2.4 (95% CI 1.5, 3.3; p=0.002)". In another journal in which the readership consists of epidemiologists, test scores, degrees of freedom, coefficients of determination and others are reported. For example, "race was found to be associated with disease severity $(\chi_{df=4}^2=24.3; p<0.001)$".

In these situations, it's not correct to assume that the level of scrutiny is less in the first compared to the second. If we deemed it necessary, we would require authors to present more information about their statistical procedures. In fact, it is more and more common to have supplementary material appended to full manuscripts that describe the statistical methods and results in (often exhausting) detail.

I do hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. I have a follow up question in your example - what does χ2(df=4) mean? I know df means degrees of freedom and p is the p value but I'm not sure what the other part mean.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to make it more complicated than it was. I apologise. I meant to say that the chi-square test had 4 degrees of freedom and that the result of the test -- that is to say, the actual value of $\chi^2=\sum \frac{(O-E)^2}{E}$ -- was 24.3. Finally, the p-value for this result is less than 1 in a thousand.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is no agreement. Practically, the journal you submit to should have guidelines, and they vary widely. For instance, the well-known journal Psycholigical Science requires (or required - haven't checked) reporting the 'p-rep' statistic, when no other journal I know of does similarly.

In my mind, you want to report everything needed for a reader to not only gauge effect size and p-value (which you've done), but *also* assess whether the analysis was done properly. For this reason I always stress that degrees-of-freedom be reported. I have come across many examples in published papers where the reported *df* suggest data aggregation was not done properly.  Similarly, *df* lets me know that you've included all your data and haven't been dropping cases without explanation.

That said, many journals have fairly lax reporting guidelines, but you'll have to check to see what is standard in your field/journal.